# rvictl is not working

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, network-monitoring

i'm trying to monitor all traffic on my iphone. so i googled about the tools, and i found rvictl is my choice. [based on this article](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/remote-packet-capture-for-ios-devices/)

i've got xcode installed before this, so i run "rvictl" in the terminal, gave nothing, but no error either, that means rvictl is installed already.

so i tried to run "rvictl -s 7BE4CC277XXXXXXXXXX" and waited for about 2 seconds, then nothing happend or showed, just nothing

leideMacBook-Air:~ Jack$ rvictl -s 7BE4CC2772E3D50174C49ABxxxxxx
leideMacBook-Air:~ Jack$

just like that, so i googled and saw another article here [repair your xcode pkg](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/73123) by reinstall those 2 pkgs, and hit again
still got the same, nothing happens

so can anyone give another clue to fix this?

Answer (score 9):

For me, the issue happens, when I use UPPERCASE UUID, instead of lowercase one:

```
// does not work:
$ rvictl -s F320D3ED185C4CD28FC96E48119D6E39

// works:
$ rvictl -s f320d3ed185c4cd28fc96e48119d6e39
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what worked for me:

Make sure that all letters are lower case, took me a min to figure this out.

```
za:news za$ rvictl -s 8adca3ef84c9d647d32644a30cc448185ae39108

Starting device 8adca3ef84c9n647d32644a30cc448185de39108 [SUCCEEDED] with interface rvi0
```

The new interface is now added, this one rvi0:

```
$ ifconfig -l
lo0 gif0 stf0 en0 en1 en2 p2p0 awdl0 bridge0 `rvi0`
```

When running the command with all upper case,upper cased UUID number, no sterr no stdout either, just dies silently:

```
za$ rvictl -s 8ADCA3EF84C9D647N32644A30CC448185DE39108
za$ rvictl -L

Could not get list of devices
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the UDID of my device from Apple Logo -> About This Mac -> System Report -> click on device -> copy Serial Number looked like

```
AAAABBBBBBBxxxxx // no hyphen, doesn't work!
```

But when I copied from XCode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators -> select device -> copy 'Identifier' it looked like

```
AAAA-BBBBBBBxxxxx // has hyphen
```

The one with the hyphen worked:

```
rvictl -s AAAA-BBBBBBBxxxxx // works!
```

Answer (score -3):

well, run the command with root's privilege......